# C++ error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token when their is

Tags: c++, string, syntax, compiler-errors, char

I am trying to create a function that will return the alphabet position of a letter that is passed into the function 
for example

```
cout<<getPosition('l')
```

would return the integer 12. I am fairly certain I have got the logic correct however I am having some trouble with the syntax. I found many similar questions however I still was not able to solve the problem.
Any help appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getPosition(letter)
{
    int pos = 0;
    const char alphabet[26]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    for (int counter=0; counter!=26; counter++)
    {
        if (alphabet[counter] == letter)
        {
            pos = counter;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

int main()
{
    string letter = 'r';
    cout << posInAlpha(letter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a parameter type in your function. Should be `int getPosition(char letter)`.

Comment: cout<<posInAlpha(letter); but your function is getPosition.

Comment: rethink what the return value shall be if the letter is not contained in the alphabet. Note `0` is a valid position in the alphabet (representing the first character).

Comment: If correctly understood what you're trying to do, you're heading in the wrong direction: `int getPosition( const char c ) { return c - 'a'; }`

Comment: @StephanLechner Given the example, 0 is not a valid position in the alphabet and there is a bug where it can be returned for `'a'` anyway.

Comment: Note that, if your goal with this function is to actually use it instead of to learn C++, there is a simpler way. The letters are guaranteed to be continuous; you can just `return letter - 'a' + 1;` and not go through all the hassle. (The `+ 1` part is needed in your definition here, too, if you want `getPosition('l')` to be 12 instead of 11.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing `std::string` and `char`, while you don't need the first. Moreover, your `main()` uses a function not declared. Furthermore, your function's parameter lacks it's type. Your compiler should be pretty explanatory for these. I modified your code to get the desired behavior; please take a moment or two understanding what had to be modified here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Returns the index of 'letter' in alphabet, or -1 if not found.
int getPosition(char letter)
{
    int pos = -1;
    const char alphabet[26]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    for (int counter=0;counter!=26;counter++)
    {
        if (alphabet[counter]==letter)
        {
            pos=counter;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

int main()
{
    char letter='r';
    cout<<getPosition(letter);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 17

I initialized `pos` to -1, in case `letter` does not belong in the alphabet. Otherwise the function would return 0, meaning that `a` was the answer.

---

PS: If `letter` was an `std::string`, then your comparison with every letter of the alphabet would produce a compilation error, since the types do not match.

Comment: had a feeling it was something simple like that... thanks anyways

Comment: I'd init `pos` with some sort of `NOT_FOUND`, e.g. `#define NOT_FOUND -1`. Otherwise one would return a valid result even if `letter` is not part of the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

it all begins here

```
int getPosition(letter)
{
```

this function is not right declared/defined, letter must be a type and you just gave none...

assuming this

```
char letter = 'r';
cout << posInAlpha(letter);
```

that letter must be a char and the function posInAlpha should be renamed to `getPosition`

it all looks like you are mixing std::strings and chars,

your final fixed code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getPosition(char& letter)
{
    int pos = 0;
    const char alphabet[26] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };
    for (int counter = 0; counter != 26; counter++)
    {
        if (alphabet[counter] == letter)
        {
            pos = counter;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

int main()
{
    char letter = 'r';
    cout << getPosition(letter);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

which prints ***17*** for the given char ***'r'***

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int getPosition( char c )
{
  c |= 0x20; // to lower
  return ( c < 'a' || c > 'z' )
    ? -1
    : c - 'a';
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << getPosition( 'R' );
  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/LM0UzU)